# How to view the progress of a cf push command to CloudFoundary

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am trying to push a large WAR file to CloudFoundary using cf push command.
Is there a way to view the progress of how much has been pushed to the remote server in this command using any parameters?

Answer (score 7):

As of v6.3 (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases) I don't believe there is a nice progress bar for upload.

One option, if you're debugging and trying to ensure that upload is actually happening, is to turn on tracing.

```
export CF_TRACE=true
cf push
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now,I cant see any progress bar option,but you can see the log files once the push is successful. explore all logs available in the container, first view the log filenames, then view the log that interests you(just an alternative to see the progress bar via logs):

```
$ cf files my-app logs/
Getting files for app my-app in org my-org / space development as a.user@example.com...
OK

staging_task.log                          844B
stderr.log                                182B
stdout.log                                  0B

$ cf files my-app logs/stderr.log
Getting files for app my-app in org my-org / space development as a.user@example.com...
OK

[2014-01-27 20:21:58] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-01-27 20:21:58] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-11-22) [x86_64-linux]
[2014-01-27 20:21:58] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=31 port=64391
```